# SQL Insert multiple entries non auto increment primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

How can I insert into non auto increment primary key?

As you can see the select has at least 100 rows and for every insert I need to get the latest incremented ID. I can't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and we can't modify the database structure.

Currently getting the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DOCUMENT'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DOCUMENTS'

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] 
     (DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_TYPE, DOCUMENT_REF, DOCUMENT_NOTE,
      DOCUMENT_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
      DOCUMENT_FUNCTION_CODE, BATCH_ID, AUDIT_XML, AUDIT_USER, REMINDER_DATE)
    SELECT TOP 100
        (SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) + 1 FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS),
        NULL, NULL,
        'MIGRATED FROM BRING UP NOTES ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + sr.BRINGUP_NOTES,
        GETDATE(), NULL, NULL,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, sr.BRINGUP_DATE
    FROM 
        [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr
    WHERE 
        BRINGUP_NOTES IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 
        SERVICE_REQUEST_ID DESC
```

Comment: Any help? Below answer from Gordon does not work

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `identity` column. But absent that, you can use `row_number()`:

```
   SELECT TOP 100
          (SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
          . . .
```

This will not work on an empty table.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff It is a old database design used for multiple sources so it is safer not to modify the structure

Comment: Got this error
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff Not sure why

Comment: Any idea? This is new.

Comment: @ove . . . The subquery in this answer cannot return more than one row; it is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` (`(SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS)`).

Comment: Can you update the answer? You mean the group by should be added at the end?

Comment: @ove . . . Not at all.  The query has no `GROUP BY` on purpose.

Comment: I can't make this to work. What is the solution? thanks

Comment: any alternative solution?
Was trying something like
(SELECT TOP 1 [DOCUMENT_ID] FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS ORDER BY DOCUMENT_ID DESC but i can't add 1 to it

Comment: @ove . . . Your query would appear to have other problems.  The code in this answer should solve the `document_id` problem, assuming `document_id` is numeric.

Comment: document_id is int. Not sure what other problems you mean. Do I need to cast it?

Comment: I am inserting like 100 rows into the table. That's why there can be multiple values returned from the select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....... Use Row number in addition of Max document id

```
         INSERT INTO [dbo].[DOCUMENTS] 
         (DOCUMENT_ID, DOCUMENT_TYPE, DOCUMENT_REF, DOCUMENT_NOTE,
          DOCUMENT_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
          DOCUMENT_FUNCTION_CODE, BATCH_ID, AUDIT_XML, AUDIT_USER, REMINDER_DATE)
        SELECT TOP 100
            (SELECT MAX(DOCUMENT_ID) + 1 FROM dbo.DOCUMENTS) + ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY SERVICE_REQUEST_ID DESC),
            NULL, NULL,
            'MIGRATED FROM BRING UP NOTES ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + sr.BRINGUP_NOTES,
            GETDATE(), NULL, NULL,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, sr.BRINGUP_DATE
        FROM 
            [dbo].[SERVICE_REQUESTS] sr
        WHERE 
            BRINGUP_NOTES IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY 
            SERVICE_REQUEST_ID DESC
```